# Javascript: onchange use the same div and print from 2 different ids

Tags: javascript, html

when input change print the color to background. Simple Color is a HEX color, and the Colorful background is a gradient color.

When someone changing the Simple color change the background with that id `('smplID')` and the same for the colorful background `('clrfID')`. This is my HTML `<div id="previewBG"></div>` and the Javascript:

```
       document.getElementById("divID").onchange = function() {previewBG()};

    function previewBG()
    {
        var simpleColor = document.getElementById('smplID').value; // just a HEX #FFFFFF
        var ColorfulBG = document.getElementById('clrfID').value; // Gradient color starts with background: linear-gradient(45deg....
        var divID = document.getElementById('divID'); // the Div im changing the Background Color

        divID.style.background = simpleColor; // style="background: #THECOLOR"
        divID.style = ColorfulBG; // style="background: linear-gradient(45deg...."
    }
```

its print only the one id to that div..
i tried to add an `if( simpleColor ) { divID.style.background = simpleColor; }` but nothing.
sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nikos, 
Your English is fine; unfortunately my Greek is terrible so I'm afraid I will have to respond in English as well!

I think you need to wrap the two lines where you set the background color of divID in if statements to check if a simpleColor and ColorfulBG are provided. If only a simpleColor is given just set the background to that:

```
if(simpleColor && !ColorfulBG) {
divID.style.background = simpleColor; 
}
```

if a ColorfulBG is also input, use both inputs to create the gradient:

```
if (simpleColor && ColorfulBG) {
divID.style.background = 'linear-gradient(45deg,' + simpleColor + ',' +  ColorfulBG + ')'; 
}
```

You could also attach the onChange event to your inputs rather than the surrounding div as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="smplID" placeholder="#CECECE" onchange="previewBG()" />
<input type="text" id="clrfID" placeholder="Gradient color" onchange="previewBG()" />
```

or unobtrusively like this:

```
document.getElementById("smplID").onchange = function() {previewBG()}; document.getElementById("clrfID").onchange = function() {previewBG()};
```

```js
document.getElementById("smplID").onchange = function() {previewBG()};

document.getElementById("clrfID").onchange = function() {previewBG()};

function previewBG()
{
    var simpleColor = document.getElementById('smplID').value; // just a HEX #FFFFFF
    var ColorfulBG = document.getElementById('clrfID').value; // Gradient color starts with background: linear-gradient(45deg....
    var divID = document.getElementById('divID'); // the Div im changing the Background Color
    
 //If only a SimpleColor is entered make that the background   
if(simpleColor && !ColorfulBG) {
    divID.style.background = simpleColor; // style="background: 
    }
    
//if a SimpleColor and ColorfuLBG is entered make a gradient  
 if (simpleColor && ColorfulBG) {
    divID.style.background = 'linear-gradient(45deg,' + simpleColor + ',' +  ColorfulBG + ')'; // style="background: linear-gradient(45deg...."
    }// style="background: linear-gradient(45deg...."
}
```

```css
div#divID {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="divID">
  <input type="text" id="smplID" placeholder="#CECECE" />
  <input type="text" id="clrfID" placeholder="Gradient color" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggetion but robert, i have a gradient color generator that provides me the css Code take a look: https://imgur.com/9bU8Qv1
& this is why i use `divID.style = ColorfulBG` because my css code starts with `background:`

Comment: Thanks. It did. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS create a class called `.color-a { background: blue; }`. Use javascripts `.classList` method to add/remove/toggle the `.color-a` CSS class on the container element (`body` or `section` or `div` or whatever) on your event of choice, `change`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

or i think i'll use another event the simpleColor is printed `onChange()` and the colorful one i'll set it `onMouseup()` i have tested and it works but if you have a better js code i'll appreciate that